# NestJs TypeORM Optimised way of saving Many-to-Many

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I am trying to save a simple many to many news to tags, this is my structure.

It works. But I don't like the code in the service. It does not seem the clean optimised way to do it.

-- POST body

```
{
    "url": "https://link.com",
    "tags" : [2,4]
}
```

What is the official, best-practice way to handle this many-to-many save?

-- news.entity.ts

```
@ManyToMany(() => Tag, (tag) => tag.news, { cascade: true })
@JoinTable({name : "news_tags"})
tags: Tag[]
```

-- tag.entity.ts

```
@ManyToMany(() => News, (news) => news.tags)
news: News[]
```

-- createNews.dto.ts

```
export class CreateNewsDto {
    
    @IsNotEmpty({message: "Url is required"})
    @IsUrl({ message: 'URL is not valid.' })
    url: string;

    tags: [];
}
```

-- news.service.ts

```
async createNews(newsDto: CreateNewsDto){
   const tags: Array<Tag> = [];
   newsDto.tags.forEach(async tagId => {
      const tag = await this.tagRepository.findOne(tagId);
      if(!tag) {
           throw new NotFoundException('Tag not found!');
      }
      tags.push(tag);
   });
   const news = await this.newsRepository.save(newsDto);
   news.tags = tags;
   return await this.newsRepository.save(news);
}
```

-- news.controller.ts

```
@Post("/create") 
@UsePipes(ValidationPipe)
async createNews(@Body() newsData: CreateNewsDto){
   return await this.newsService.createNews(newsData); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I Don't think forEach support async operations, to make your function perfom better, use `findByIds` instead of using loop, here's how:

```
  async createNews(newsDto: CreateNewsDto){
   const tags: Array<Tag> = await this.tagRepository.findByIds(newsDto.tags);
   news.tags = tags;
   return await this.newsRepository.save(news);
}
```